# How to update model property automatically from view model?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

EDIT - adding more "realistic code" per comment.  Design goal is that all models are wrapped by view models and the view model acts as a proxy to the model.  The view never binds directly to a model.  Also, I have a separate javascript class that sends and receives models to/from the server that is injected as a dependency into the view models.

Below, the `MessageModel`'s `content` is the raw content the user typed and/or what the server returned.  `MessageViewModel` exposes a message property which is a formatted version of the model's `content` property.

```
function MessageModel(id, content, nick) {
    var self = this;
    self.nick = nick;
    self.content = content;
    self.id = id;
}

// view needs to bind to properties that only exist on the view model
function MessageViewModel(messageModel, dataService) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(messageModel.id);
    self.message = ko.computed(function() {
        // format the content for the view
        return messageModel.nick + " <" + messageModel.content + ">";
    });
    self.saveMessage(function() {
        // send the model up to the server
        dataService.saveMessage(self.model);
    });
    self.model = messageModel;
}
```

With what I wrote above, changes to the view model need to be pushed to the model and when receiving models from the server, changes need to be pushed to be reflected in the view model and then to the view.  How to do this in knockout?

Comment: if you want to update `messageModel.id` through binding then it must be `observable`; currently the viewModel id is your only observable

Comment: @house9 - don't want to update model through binding.  Want to update view model through binding and then update the model using the view model.  It's not good to couple a model directly to the view.

Comment: You should show more realistic code. It doesn't make sense to create an object to hold an `id`, and then wrap it in another object with another `id` to finish having two dependent `id` observables. If the `id` was all what you nedd, I'm sure you'd only have a simple view model with an `id`. So, please, make the sample more realistic, explaining why you have a nested model, what you want to happen with it when the parent's `id` changes and so on. Can you improve your question with this information?

Comment: I think your best bet might be to register subscriptions on the observables and then you can update your models from the subscription callback - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables - however this level of abstraction is going to generate a lot more code which might be a worse trade off then just binding your model to the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to think of modeling the application rather than implementing a data model separately in your app code. The data model is on the server, isn't it? It's entirely redundant to copy values from your viewmodel to your data model within the app. Copy them to the server.
But if you want to, you can [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the observable and copy the value elsewhere.

See the docs on [MVVM and ViewModels](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#mvvm-and-view-models) and note the distinction is between the "stored" data and the data in the app. The data is (usually) stored on a server. Once you've brought it into the app, it's viewmodel data. The interface between the viewmodel and the model is (usually) the ajax calls that load data to the app and save them back to the server.

The only thing you need to model in javascript is your application, because that's all you're writing. It's not a data source for anything else. If the actual data model changes, you either need to change the behavior of the app, or you can isolate the changes to the loading and saving routines. There is zero value in having an intermediate data model.

Comment: Yeah, what you are saying isn't MVVM at all.  It's perfectly normal to have view models that have some or all of the same properties as the model.  As far as a server (which has nothing to do with MVVM), DTOs are what should be transferred over the wire (which my models currently are).  I will look at subscribe though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10636745)

Comment: @AlexJolig I answered the question in the last sentence of the first paragraph, but I have expanded on my answer in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @RoyJ - yes, but after I get them via the ajax call I have to store them in objects in javascript, which is why I have models written in javascript.

Comment: @O.O Updated again. You're describing the interface between the model (on the server) and the app. Yes, you need an interface. It's an adapter, though, not a duplicate of the model.

Comment: @RoyJ - I updated my question as well to show the design I'm after.  Do you still think subscribe is the way to go?

Comment: @O.O subscribe is the tool made for the purpose of responding to changes in observables, so it is what you want.